# System of equations solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following and I need to know how to get a2 and a3

[image]

Comment: Isolate $a_2 + a_3$ and $2a_2 + 3a_3$ in the bottom two equations, and then proceed as you normally would to solve a system of two linear equations in two unknowns.

Comment: Obligatory show-what-you-tried comment

Comment: @Laertes The OP is reading a solution in a book and is unable to understand the solution. "Show what you tried" is not an appropriate answer to someone who is struggling to follow an explanation.

Comment: @user49640 My apologies, I misunderstood

Comment: Sooner or later, you will have to work with matrices. The result says that the inverse of matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&1&1&1\\0&1&2&3\end{pmatrix}$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\-3&-2&3&-1\\2&1&-2&1\end{pmatrix}$. Have you noticed for example why the two first rows are equal ?

Answer (score 2):

after the hint above we have
$$p_1-v_0-p_0=a_2+a_3$$ (I)
$$v_1-v_0=2a_2+3a_3$$   (II)
$(-2)I+II$:
$$-2p_1-2p_0+v_0+v_1=a_3$$
Can you finish?